# CognitoUser getUsername mehod is returning email id of user while signing up

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am working with aws cognito for registering user. It was working correctly and returing uuid of user as username. but all sudden its returning email. I have made no changes in logic. This is the response

```
  user: CognitoUser {
    username: 'dev@thebrandwick.com',
    pool: CognitoUserPool {
      userPoolId: 'MYUSERPOOLID',
      clientId: 'MYCLIENTID',
      client: [Client],
      advancedSecurityDataCollectionFlag: true,
      storage: [Function]
    },
    Session: null,
    client: Client {
      endpoint: 'ENDPOINT',
      fetchOptions: {}
    },
    signInUserSession: null,
    authenticationFlowType: 'USER_SRP_AUTH',
    storage: [Function: MemoryStorage] {
      setItem: [Function: setItem],
      getItem: [Function: getItem],
      removeItem: [Function: removeItem],
      clear: [Function: clear]
    },
    keyPrefix: 'CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.......',
    userDataKey: 'CognitoIdentityServiceProvider............'
  },
  userConfirmed: false,
  userSub: '4708ce1f-.....-4490-850d-.....',
  codeDeliveryDetails: {
    AttributeName: 'email',
    DeliveryMedium: 'EMAIL',
    Destination: 'd***@t***'
  }
}
```

This is my logic

```
export const signUp = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { firstName, lastName, password, email, phoneNumber } = req.body;

  const attributeList: CognitoUserAttribute[] = [];

  const dataEmail: CognitoUserAttribute = new CognitoUserAttribute({ Name: 'email', Value: email });
  const dataFirstName: CognitoUserAttribute = new CognitoUserAttribute({ Name: 'given_name', Value: firstName });
  const dataLastName: CognitoUserAttribute = new CognitoUserAttribute({ Name: 'family_name', Value: lastName });
  const dataPhoneNumber: CognitoUserAttribute = new CognitoUserAttribute({ Name: 'phone_number', Value: phoneNumber });

  attributeList.push(dataEmail, dataFirstName, dataLastName, dataPhoneNumber);

  userPool.signUp(email, password, attributeList, [], async (err: Error | undefined, result: ISignUpResult | undefined) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error while signing up:', err);
      return res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
    }

    if (result == undefined) {
      console.error('Error while signing up:', err);
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'No results found' });
    }

    const cognitoUser: CognitoUser = result.user;

    console.log(result);
    console.log(result.user);

    const cognitoRefId = cognitoUser.getUsername();

    console.log(cognitoRefId);

    const newUser: any = await User.create({
      cognitoRefId: cognitoRefId, 
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
      mobile: phoneNumber,
      email: email
    });

    return res.json({ message: 'User registration successful', challenge: result?.codeDeliveryDetails });
  });
};
```

Weird thing is that it was working as expected but all sudden i am facing this issue. Maybe the problem is inside cognito configuration?